# prevent click event on long press

Tags: angular, mouseevent, stoppropagation, long-press

I have the following angular2 template:

```
<div (click)="foo()">
   <img (longPress)="bar(1)" (click)="foobar(1)" />
   <img (longPress)="bar(2)" (click)="foobar(2)"/>
</div>
```

Longpress is a custom attribute directive that triggers when you have a mousedown for 500 ms.

Click events on the `<div>` and `<img>` are handled fine. When I do a longpress on an image, the bar() function is called. However, on mouseUp (after a longpress) the click events are triggered on the `<img>` and the parent `<div>`.

How can I prevent these click events in the simplest way.

Only thing I can think of now is to write a custom attribute directive that only triggers on "clicks" that take less than 500 ms. This just seems a bit over the top to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up creating a "longPress" and a "shortPress" directive.
The longpress only fires after a set amount of time and the shortpres only fires below that same threshold.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[shortPress]' })

export class ShortPressDirective {

    @Output()
    shortPress = new EventEmitter();

    private _timeout: any;
    private _isShort: boolean;

    @HostListener('mousedown') onMouseDown( e ) {
        this._isShort = true;
        this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this._isShort = false;
        }, 500);
    }

    @HostListener('mouseup') onMouseUp( e ) {
        if (this._isShort) {
            this.shortPress.emit( e );
        }
        clearTimeout(this._timeout);
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
        clearTimeout(this._timeout);
    }
}
```

and

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[longPress]' })

export class LongPressDirective {

    @Output()
    longPress = new EventEmitter();

    private _timeout: any;

    @HostListener('mousedown') onMouseDown( e ) {
        this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.longPress.emit( e );
        }, 500);
    }

    @HostListener('mouseup') onMouseUp() {
        clearTimeout(this._timeout);
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
        clearTimeout(this._timeout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing in `$event` as the first parameter, and then do a `event.stopPropagation()` in your bar()-method?
Something like this:

`<img (longPress)="bar($event,1)" (click)="foobar(1)" />`

`function bar(event:Event,myNum:number){event.stopPropagation();}`

Comment: I did think of a construction like that, but that would mean I have to alter the functions that are called. I'd rather have the solution in the attribute directive itself so it doesn't need a specific format for the functions passed to it to work.

Furthermore, the longpress would return a mousedown event. I'm not sure if stopping a mousedown prevents a click from being triggered.

Comment: @JasperZelf, doesn't that just prevent the long press event from propagating to parent elements; as opposed to preventing other events firing on host element?